# Square Connect Retrieve Transaction

Tags: square, square-connect

I've build an iOS app that uses the iOS `SquarePointOfSaleSDK` which returns me a transaction Id and nothing more. Since I need more information about the payment (e.g: method, how many tenders, etc.) I'm calling the [RetrieveTransaction](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-retrievetransaction) Connect API v2 service immediately when I receive the `transaction id` from the Square POS app and this normally works, but sometimes I get the error described below.

```
{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"NOT_FOUND","detail":"Location `XXXXXXXX` does not have a transaction with ID `YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY`.","field":"transaction_id"}]}
```

When this transaction actually exists in this location.

I'm guessing the transaction, sometimes, is not available for API actions that fast, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this, I'd really appreciate any help or guidance in this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there can sometimes be a small delay between `Charge` and the transaction actually being retrievable. Unfortunately I'm not sure on how long the delay can be but I'll make sure this gets added to our documentation.

For now, I would suggest that if the error occurs, just to have the code attempt the `RetrieveTransaction` call again, perhaps looping until it's available. You should probably also include a way to get out of it (after X time or something), just to prevent the rare possibility of an endless loop.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Yeah, that’s exactly what I’m building right now, it will be great to see the warning in the documentation to help others in the future.